# If quarks change colours constantly how are proton and neutron stable relatively?

Tags: quarks, protons, color-charge

Say for example a proton is composed of Up, Up and Down (valance) quarks and suppose the Down quark absorbs a gluon, Down quark must change colour in order to conserve colour charges but so must the other 2 Up quarks? Unless at any given point in time the 3 valance quarks are always exchanging gluons to each other simultaneously otherwise the strong force between them would not work as proton right?

Comment: Don't forget that the gluons also carry color charge. See [this anim](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Nuclear_Force_anim_smaller.gif) (which was created by [manishearth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7433/manishearth)), but bear in mind that's a highly simplified diagram, so it doesn't show the interchange of gluons between 2 gluons or a quark & a gluon, and it doesn't show the sea quarks, just the valence quarks.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I read that the sea quarks is invisible to outside so the effect is negligible but the valence quarks must add up to white colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the quarks & gluons in the proton *are* continuously exchanging gluons with their neighbouring quarks & gluons, and the total color charge must *always* add up to white, due to [color confinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement).

However, as the anim below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction#Residual_strong_force), courtesy of [manishearth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7433/manishearth)) shows, the color changes of 2 valence quarks don't need to be simultaneous. Eg, a blue quark can emit a blue-antired gluon which changes that quark's color to red, so the color remains balanced at all times.

[image: Nuclear force anim]

I should mention that color charge is actually more complicated than diagrams like the one above imply. Please see the Wikipedia article on [gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon#Eight_gluon_colours) for details. Also see [Why are there eight gluons and not nine?](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/gluons.html) by James Bottomley and John Baez.